# Shotwell, Android, thumbnails, and "IMG_filename.jpg"

Tags: android, shotwell

I'm trying to view the JPG photos on my Pixel 3a (running Android 11) with Shotwell (version .30.10) on an Ubuntu laptop (version 20.04.1). The phone mounts, but some images show no thumbnails, just an icon. From what I can tell, if a photo's filename on my phone is "IMG_1234.jpg" it is assigned a nice thumbnail, but filenames lacking the IMG_ prefix, such as "2345.jpg" are not. I think my phone's behavior may have changed from "IMG_123.jpg" to "2345.jpg" when I updated to Android 11. Is there a way to get Shotwell to provide thumbnails for "2345.jpg", or is there some other possible issue with these JPGs that's keeping them from generating thumbnails?

Comment: I am trying to understand why images whose filename begins "IMG_" show thumbnails and those that lack this prefix do not. I rewrote the above a little bit to try to clarify.

Comment: I thought if Shotwell wasn't "seeing" the JPGs without "IMG_" prefixes in their filenames, this might be able to be modified by a preference in Shotwell. Like, "generate thumbnails for all JPG files, whether or not their names start with IMG_" Perhaps I am indeed barking up the wrong tree here, or have assumed the filename is the problem when it's actually something else--I don't have a strong technical background.

Comment: What are the other differences between the files?  Surely if they were saved by the same application they would have the same file name scheme... Unless they are different somehow.  I think you should be trying to figure out how and why the files are different

Comment: Okay, yes, I think you're right--I'll do some more research to see if there are other differences between these files. I haven't posted a question here before--should I delete this one, and then phrase a new one when I have new details? Thank you for your help.

Comment: No need to delete the question unless you find a solution and determine for sure that the issue has nothing to do with Ubuntu.